# Running xcodebuild in php

Tags: php, ios, xcodebuild

I'm trying to run the xcodebuild command from within php, and it just doesn't seem to even get called. I get no output from the exec command, and no errors are thrown. Other commands are working just fine, such as xcrun (which I'm using to prepare the app for ad-hoc distribution). Here is the code I'm calling;

```
exec('/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version', $output);
print_r($output);
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit: I should add, this command runs fine from the command line, running as the same user as the php script.

Comment: I discovered that if I run the php script from the command line, then this actually works. If I run it via a browser (using Apache) then it doesn't work. This doesn't solve my problem, as I want to build a web service, but its interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs perfectly for me.

Perhaps you can change it to this and make sure the return value from the command is 0:

```
exec('/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version', $output, $rv);
echo "Command returned: $rv\n";
print_r($output);
```

If `$rv` is something other than 0, then at least you know your `exec()` call is working and it's just that the `xcodebuild` command-line is failing for some reason.

Comment: I'm trying to find out what xcodebuild exit code of 5 means, but at least I know for sure its the command not a problem with php. But, that was pretty much what I thought before. I just don't get why running the command in php fails, but from the command line it succeeds?

Answer (score 0):

I have also this problem... did you tried to give full permissions to user **nobody** ?

Answer (score 0):

After 1 day debug and try everything, i can finally build a build server for my ios app using php. I list all the things i have done here so that others can also fix their problems if they  have the same ones.

### Use shell_exec() instead of exec(), so that you can see all the output.

I have something like this to test ##

```
$output = shell_exec("xcodebuild -showsdks 2>&1");
print_r($output);
```

When i first run the above codes, i have this probem on browser

> You have not agreed to the Xcode license agreements, please run xcodebuild standalone from within a Terminal window to review and agree to the Xcode license agreements.
>   Build step 'XCode' marked build as failure
>   Finished: FAILURE

So i run

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

to agree the license system wide

Run the code again, i have this problem

> xcodebuild: error: The workspace 'xxx' does not contain a scheme named 'xxx'.

To solve this: try the checked answer of this question: [Building with xcodebuild Timed out waiting for <IDEWorkspace, 0x2004cebc0>/"runContextManager.runContexts"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959382/building-with-xcodebuild-timed-out-waiting-for-ideworkspace-0x2004cebc0-runc/7113723#7113723)

After fixing the issue, my build script now run normally.

Hope i can help you solving your issues.